# Python Pickle Module and OOP

Tags: python, oop, pickle

In the example below `pickle` crashes with every attempt to save an instance A to file.

Why does it happen?

How to avoid it?

How to get around it?

```
class Base(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Base, self).__init__()

class ClassA(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassA, self).__init__()  
    def setInstB(self, instB):
        self['instB']=instB

class ClassB(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassB, self).__init__()
    def setInstA(self, instA):
        self['instA']=instA

instA=ClassA()
instB=ClassB()

instA.setInstB(instB)
instB.setInstA(instA)

import pickle
pickle.dump( instA, open( "save.p", "wb" ) )
```

### Posted later.

If `Base(dict)` class is not declared to be a subclass of built-in `dict` the problem goes away. Running the code posted below raises no `pickle` errors. But I still want to know why pickle fails and how to make it work with Classes inheriting from `dict`.

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Base, self).__init__()

class ClassA(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassA, self).__init__()  
    def setInstB(self, instB):
        self.instB=instB

class ClassB(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassB, self).__init__()
    def setInstA(self, instA):
        self.instA=instA

instA=ClassA()
instB=ClassB()

instA.setInstB(instB)
instB.setInstA(instA)

import pickle
pickle.dump( instA, open( "save.p", "wb" ) )
```

Comment: Please show the command  used to run the script as well as the *full* error message

Comment: Your objects have recursive references to each other, so pickle gets stuck in a loop.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why do you need that circular reference?

Comment: The code is designed to work with the database objects. The database objects (represented as Python classes) are all interconnected with each other often creating the nested recursive references three, four and more levels deep. It causes absolutely no issues inside Python. But it gives me a headache with QT widgets which rely heavily on `pickle` that fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you ran into some kind of bug in pickle. I suggest you submit it, and probably it will get fixed.

Following code can fix your problems:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
class Base(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Base, self).__init__()
        pk = None

class ClassA(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassA, self).__init__()
    def setInstB(self, instB):
        self['instB']=instB

class ClassB(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassB, self).__init__()
    def setInstA(self, instA):
        self['instA']=instA

instA=ClassA()
instA.pk=1
instB=ClassB()
instB.pk=2

instA.setInstB(instB)
instB.setInstA(instA)

import pickle

class MyPickler(pickle.Pickler):
    def persistent_id(self, obj):
        return obj.pk

MyPickler(open( "save.p", "wb" )).dump(instA)
```

Pickler allows explicitly to generate unqie ids for your objects: see `persistent_id` method, and since these are database objects I guess that generating ids will be easy.

Comment: Thanks for the info jb! Do you think it is possible to find a working solution without tweaking/customizing `pickle` or its instances? Since in my situation `pickle` is called by PyQt widget...

Comment: Well I tried to debug this pickle code and IMO it's a bug in pickle, you could monkey patch ``pickle`` function and hence work around this bug.

You could also fiddle and find what causes this bug and try to patch your classes for it.

Comment: Thanks again! I found that I just can comment a line in `pickle.py` responsible for raising an error. But I don't want to customize a build-in module. I hoped to get it solved within my code (otherwise I would have to always remember to make sure a "fixed" pickle is used.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be a bug in `pickle`, as I can `pickle` what you wanted to do initially without problems.  If you use `dill` instead of `pickle`, then there's no issue… and all `dill` is is a bunch of `copy_reg` functions to register how to serialize different types that `pickle` can't handle by default.

```
dude@hilbert>$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 12 2013, 13:26:39) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class Base(dict):
...     def __init__(self):
...         super(Base, self).__init__()
... 
>>> class ClassA(Base):
...     def __init__(self):
...         super(ClassA, self).__init__()  
...     def setInstB(self, instB):
...         self['instB']=instB
... 
>>> class ClassB(Base):
...     def __init__(self):
...         super(ClassB, self).__init__()
...     def setInstA(self, instA):
...         self['instA']=instA
... 
>>> instA=ClassA()
>>> instB=ClassB()
>>> 
>>> instA.setInstB(instB)
>>> instB.setInstA(instA)
>>> 
>>> import dill as pickle
>>> pickle.dump( instA, open('save.p', 'wb') )
>>> res = pickle.load( open('save.p', 'rb') ) 
>>> res
{'instB': {'instA': {...}}}
>>> res['instB']
{'instA': {'instB': {...}}}
```

Get `dill` here:
  https://github.com/uqfoundation